# Kindly advice on how to group the data in SQL

Tags: sql, db2

Example table

```
Cust_no | Item_no | Discount_Amt |Discount_%|
A123    | ITEM123 |          0.1 |          |
AB321   | ITEM123 |           50 |          |
A123    | ITEM123 |              |       3  |
CD343   | ITEM345 |              |       2  |
```

and the result I want:

```
Cust_no | Item_no | Discount Amt| Discount_%|
A123    | ITEM123 |       0.1   |     3     |
AB321   | ITEM123 |       50    |    0      |
CD343   | ITEM345 |             |    2      |
```

How can I get that result in SQL?

Comment: Which DBMS you are using?

Comment: It's not obvious how to group. E.g. where did CD343 go?

Comment: Hi Mr. Jibin Balachandran. I'm trying pull data from DB2 using winsql.

Comment: Hi Jarlh, CD343 should be show at below ABC321. Sorry I miss the data.

Comment: Seems you should check the `join` instead of `grouping`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
SELECT Cust_no,Item_no,SUM(Discount_Amt),SUM(Discount_%)
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Cust_no,Item_no
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a `GROUP BY` here?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt its typo Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking something similar to this

```
SELECT Cust_no,Item_no, MAX(Discount_Amt),MAX(Discount_%) 
FROM Table 
GROUP BY Cust_no, Item_no
```